# IndexError when sorting on "field x" in a string when not all strings split to "x" number of fields

Tags: python, sorting

One of the [PyBites Code Challenges](https://codechalleng.es/bites/5/), simplified here, involves sorting a list of names by last name:

```
>>> names = ['Al Pacino', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
['Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

This approach works fine for the given example but breaks if any of the strings split into less than two parts.  For example, adding "Madonna":

```
>>> names = ['Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split()[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

One could perhaps pad the split strings out to the required length with empty strings:

```
def last_name(name, last_name_field=2):
    name_split = name.split()
    while len(name_split) < 2:
        name_split.append('')
    return name_split[last_name_field - 1]
```

such that:

```
>>> names = ['Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
>>> sorted(names, key=last_name)
['Madonna', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

Is there a better way?

**Clarification**: The answers to date offer alternative ways to sort on the last element in a split string.  Thank you -- these are all very useful!

However, as my question did not make sufficiently clear -- my fault -- what I actually want is a way to sort on a given element (or field) of split strings that will not raise an exception and fail if any of the split strings have less than the required number of fields.

Essentially, I am looking for a way to get the same results as the Unix sort command, as in the following example, which sorts on field 2:

```
$ sort +1 -2 Madonna.txt   # sorts by field 2
Madonna                    # without a field 2, sorts before the others
Leonardo Da Vinci          # sorts on Da (before Damon)
Matt Damon
Robert Downey Jr           # sorts on Downey, not Jr
Scarlett Johansson
Al Pacino
```

My idea of "padding out" the split strings (see above) was based on the observation that empty strings sort before non-empty strings, e.g.:

```
>>> sorted(['Al', 'Joe', 'Hachim', '', 'Greta'])
['', 'Al', 'Greta', 'Hachim', 'Joe']
```

My question, then, was whether there is a more efficient way to achieve this result, whether by padding out the split strings more efficiently or by taking an entirely different approach.

Comment: What should happen in case a string has no two parts?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would assume the last part of each string is considered to be the last name. Right, OP?

Comment: @timgeb: What about `'Leonardo Da Vinci'`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem then the algorithm breaks :P

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I'd rather not consider what constitutes a "last name".  I'm really just looking for a way to sort by an arbitrary field, such as the "second field" or the "twentieth field", and I'm happy to assume that empty fields (i.e., non-existent fields) sort before non-empty fields.

Comment: @timgeb I have added a clarification of how I would want `Leonardo Da Vinci` to be handled in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from @OMarMohamed's answer that `sorted()` sorts a list of one-item lists on the basis of the content of their items such that

```
sorted([['Downey'], ['Damon'], ['Johansson'], ['Pacino'], ['Da'], []])
```

returns

```
[[], ['Da'], ['Damon'], ['Downey'], ['Johansson'], ['Pacino']]
```

I therefore propose the one-liner, which uses the Decorate-Sort-Undecorate idiom:

```
def dsusort(items, sortfield):
    return [t[1] for t in sorted([(item.split()[sortfield-1:sortfield], item) for item  in items])]
```

which works as follows:

```
>>> items  = ['Leonardo Da Vinci', 'Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Scarlett Johansson', 'Matt Damon', 'Robert Downey Jr']
>>> dsusort(items, 2)
['Madonna', 'Leonardo Da Vinci', 'Matt Damon', 'Robert Downey Jr', 'Scarlett Johansson', 'Al Pacino']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last element of a list, don't hardcode the index `1`, use the index `-1`.

```
>>> names = ['Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda name: name.split()[-1])
['Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Madonna', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

Comment: Will break on empty strings or strings consisting only of whitespace unlike partition/rpartition, but that's a different kettle of fish I guess :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah, no reason to work around all the iffy cases without any specs what should happen.

Comment: @timgeb Yes, that works for sorting on the last field, but it does not solve the problem of sorting on the second (or third or fiftieth) field when there are items with less than two (or three or fifty) fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing:

```
def split_name(name, last_field=2):
    return name.split()[last_field-1:last_field]

split_name("Matt Damon") # => ["Damon"]
split_name("Madonna") # => []
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @OMarMohamed Like the proposal above, that solves the problem of sorting on the last field but not the problem of sorting on the second field when there are items with less than two fields.

Comment: @OMarMohamed Thank you - that is clearer, but like other answers, it addresses the problem of sorting on the last field which, as I have now clarified (see Clarification above), is not actually what I am looking for.  My apologies for the confusion!

Comment: @TomBaker actually you can change `last_field` argument to whatever field you prefer!

Comment: @OMarMohamed Turned into a lambda, this appears to work as a sort key: `sorted(names, key=lambda name: name.split()[field-1:field])`.  As far as I can tell, this works because Python sorts a list of one-item lists (such as `[['Downey'], ['Damon'], ['Johansson'], ['Pacino'], ['Da'], []]`) on the basis of the strings they contain. So `sorted(empty_names)` gets `[[], ['Da'], ['Damon'], ['Downey'], ['Johansson'], ['Pacino']]` Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.rpartition` which guarantees a 3-tuple response, even if no split was made, you'll get an empty string, eg:

```
>>> names = ['Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
>>> sorted(names, key=lambda L: L.rpartition(' ')[2])
['Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Madonna', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

It's also optimised for splitting once - and is faster than using `str.split` with a `maxsplit=1` for instance (and far better than splitting the entire string at every delimiter).

Comment: `rpartition` seems interesting.

Comment: @JonClements This solution is interesting, but it assumes that the fields in the string are separated by a single space (as they happen to be here).  I do not see how it could be used to sort on an arbitrary field.

Comment: @Tom to be fair though - your question doesn't state what "arbitrary" is in any sense... it reads as "I want to sort on the last word"...

Comment: @TomBaker I had a quick look at the site - it appears you're after something similar to: `min(sorted({el.title().rpartition(' ') for el in names}, reverse=True, key=len))` - I'll leave you to work out the actual details.

Comment: @JonClements Fair enough - I wasn't clear on this.  I want to be able to sort a list of strings on the basis of an arbitrary "field" (in the case given, the field happens to be the last field), even if not all of the strings in the list, when split, have the required number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) to grab the last part regardless of its ordinal index:

```
names = ['Al Pacino', 'Matt Damon', 'Cher','Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves', 'Madonna']
names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1:])
print(names)

['Sandra Bullock', 'Cher', 'Matt Damon', 'Madonna', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out, this will not prioritize single word names to the front. Here's an alternate solution that does:

```
names = ['Al Pacino', 'Matt Damon', 'Cher','Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves', 'Madonna']
names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1:][0] if ' ' in x else '0' + x)
print(names)

['Cher', 'Madonna', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

Comment: Like several of the proposals above, this shows how to sort on the last field of a string, but not for an arbitrary field. If Madonna is considered to be a first name without a last name, then it would be in the wrong position.

Comment: Gotcha, I updated the answer to push single word names to the front.

Comment: Many thanks for this, which does sort in the correct order.  However, as I explain in a Clarification (above), that is not exactly the problem I am trying to solve.  My apologies for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
names = ['Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Matt Damon', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Keanu Reeves']
new_names = sorted(names, key=lambda x:(len(x.split()), re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+$', x)[0])))
```

Output:

```
['Madonna', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Matt Damon', 'Al Pacino', 'Keanu Reeves']
```

**Edit on clarification**: sorting on the second part of name:

```
import itertools
s = ['Leonardo Da Vinci', 'Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Scarlett Johansson', 'Matt Damon', 'Robert Downey Jr']
new_s = sorted([(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:len(x.split()) == 1), key=lambda x:len(x.split()) == 1)], key=lambda x:x[0], reverse = True)
final_s = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([sorted(b) if a else sorted(b, key=lambda x:x.split()[1:][0]) for a, b in new_s]))
```

Output:

```
['Madonna', 'Leonardo Da Vinci', 'Matt Damon', 'Robert Downey Jr', 'Scarlett Johansson', 'Al Pacino']
```

Comment: This is also interesting but the output is different from what I expect (see question).  For my purposes, I am not interested in sorting on the last field in the strings, but on the second field (which happens here to be the last field).

Comment: Thank you - this does achieve the expected result.  However, as I explain in a Clarification above, it does not exactly address the problem I am trying to solve (sorting on field 2, as opposed to sorting on the last field).  My apologies for the confusion!

Comment: This is impressive though I find it really difficult to read!  I also get different results when I start with a list in a different order, e.g., `s = ['Leonardo Da Vinci', 'Al Pacino', 'Madonna', 'Scarlett Johansson', 'Matt Damon', 'Robert Downey Jr']`.

Comment: @TomBaker my apologies! I tested on the wrong input, and hence and the wrong output. I made several changes in the sorting keys, and it works now. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: This is really impressive, and `itertools.chain` is a great innovation, though I do find it a bit difficult to read.  I have proposed a simpler solution below.

Comment: @TomBaker your solution certainly much simpler!